# How to delete a specific string from a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

```
features = ['ar','ar urticaria','urticaria','including','allergic']
rubbish_words = ['including','ar']
words = []
for line in features:
    new_words = ' '.join([word for word in line.split() if not any([zeyda in word for zeyda in rubbish_words])])
    words.append(new_words)
print(words)
```

`['', '', '', '', 'allergic']`

Result expected :
['',' urticaria','urticaria','','allergic']

Comment: `words = [' '.join([word for word in feature.split() if word not in rubbish_words]) for feature in features]`

Comment: @matszwecja feature is already a word, your split and double iteration will do nothing

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki One of the example features contains two words.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the *features*. Split each token. Build a list from those tokens but exclude any that are found in *rubbish_words*. Reconstruct (join) and append to new output list.

```
features = ['ar','ar urticaria','urticaria','including','allergic']
rubbish_words = ['including','ar']

new_words = []

for w in features:
    tl = [w_ for w_ in w.split() if w_ not in rubbish_words]
    new_words.append(''.join(tl))
        
print(new_words)
```

**Output:**

```
['', 'urticaria', 'urticaria', '', 'allergic']
```